# Drupal on Windows Azure generates 'No such file or directory in sqlsrv_requirements()'

Tags: azure, drupal-7

**The use case**

I have installed drupal on Windows Azure using the gallery. The database is SQL server Basic.

The installation went well despite an error due to the inability to send an email.

after the installation, Drupal proposes to perform immediate updates.

I accepted to do the upgrades and errors start to pop up.

**Could you help me and tell me what to do?**

> Warning: include_once(D:\home\site\wwwroot/includes/database/sqlsrv/reflexiondata.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in sqlsrv_requirements() (line 10 of D:\home\site\wwwroot\profiles\acquia\modules\sqlsrv\sqlsrv.install).
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'D:\home\site\wwwroot/includes/database/sqlsrv/reflexiondata.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in sqlsrv_requirements() (line 10 of D:\home\site\wwwroot\profiles\acquia\modules\sqlsrv\sqlsrv.install).